# Dynamic mpdf filename

Tags: php, pdf, syntax, mpdf

I am trying to create dynamic pdf file names based on the user who is logged in using mpdf

now in my mind this (or something similar) should work - but doesn't.

```
$User = $_POST ['Username']
$filename = $User
$Extension = ".pdf";

$mpdf->Output($filename, $Extension ,'F');
```

**Which returns the error:**

> *mPDF error: Incorrect output destination: .PDF*

**and**

```
$mpdf->Output($filename $Extension ,'F');
```

**or**

```
$mpdf->Output($filename$Extension ,'F');
```

*doesn't create the file.*

**This**

```
$mpdf->Output($filename,'F');
```

**creates the file but without the `.pdf` extension**

Help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to mpdf documentation

```
$mpdf->Output('filename.pdf','F');
```

Your code code seems to be ok. But you missed the extention in your code, try to modify your code with bellow lines.

```
$filename=$filrname.".pdf";//You might be not adding the extension, 
$mpdf->Output($filename,'F');
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to use a string operator to concenate filename and extension?

```
$mpdf->Output($filename . $Extension ,'F');
```

Cheers

Comment: Ist not exact the same. The trhead owner tried to concenate filename and extension as a paremter. @Jitendra Kumar. Balla but it in a variable and added the extension as a string not as the thread starter as a variable. I think my answer is more on the asked question as the accepted answer aslo if both work.